# Transforming unique rows to columns in excel while keeping their values

Tags: database, excel, vba

I am currently trying to work out a problem: I want to clean-up a system that has a product's parameters written in one column and their values next to them, whereas it should have the parameters as different columns with values underneath them. In addition, some products don't have some parameters.

This is perfectly illustrated by the example below:

[image: Illustration of issue and goal]

Is this only possible with macros and code? What are the options to do this for reasonably large databases?

Comment: It is possible with formula, but with large amounts of data it is not the best solution.  You will want vba.

Comment: It would be most reasonable to perform this function with code; the formula method would... take a while longer.  Automation is your friend.  If you have any code you've tried yourself, please provide so we can work to help you advance code to a working solution.  Note that Stack Overflow does not simply code for people, but collaborates to help fix issues with coding.  A suggestion for this particular topic would be to loop through your initial data and use a Select Case for parameters, assuming your list of physical characteristics would have be fixed maximum parameters.

Comment: I'll try to work through some code tonight and post results tomorrow.

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or later, you can use `Power Pivot`, aka `Get & Transform` in 2016.  Merely Pivot on the `Parameter` Column; select `Value` for the `Values` column, and `do not aggregate` under `Advanced Options`.  It will produce exactly what you show.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!